# how increate etry/count in scrapy when geting 503 error

Tags: python, scrapy

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [// i have 800 url here
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'author': quote.xpath('span/small/text()').get(),
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
            }
```

some times server become too busy and can't answer to all of my requests (i get 503) how can i increase retry count on these urls?(tell scrapy to send that request again until get the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can simply set the variable RETRY_TIMES (in settings.py) to the number of times you want to retry the request
- If the server is blocking your requests, it probably means you're overloading it with requests which is something to avoid. Putting a DOWNLOAD_DELAY (wait time between requests), and using AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED=True (increase wait time if the server is responding slowly) can help to reduce the load on the server. You can also limit the number of concurrent requests using CONCURRENT_REQUESTS.